# Express/node cookie connect.sid missing on client in production (Heroku) although visible on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cookies, graphql

I have a React App that is deployed on Netlify and a GraphQL/express backend deployed on Heroku.

I use the `connect.sid` cookie to the server to persist login and handle other backend requests e.g. stripe payments. The cookie is generated in my local development environment; however, in production (server + postgres db deployed on Heroku + client deployed on Netlify) the `connect.sid` cookie is not sent back to the client.

However, when viewing the Heroku logs, I can tell that the cookie is being generated. It is just not usable or visible by the client.

Here is my node server:

```
const startServer = async () => {
  if (typeOrmOptions.url) {
    await createConnection(typeOrmOptions); // --> was this before
  } else {
    await createConnection(); // --> was this before
  }

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }: any) => ({ req }),
    introspection: true,
    playground: true
  });

  const app = express();

  const forceSsl = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] !== "https") {
      return res.redirect(["https://", req.get("Host"), req.url].join(""));
    }
    return next();
  };

  app.use(forceSsl);

  app.set("trust proxy", 1);

  app.use(
    session({
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 86400000,
        domain
      },
      store: new MemoryStore({
        checkPeriod: 86400000 // prune expired entries every 24h
      }),
      secret: "keyboard cat"
    })
  );

  server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: {
      origin: webUrl,
      credentials: true
    }
  });

  app.listen({ port: port }, () =>
    console.log(
      ` Server ready at http://localhost:${port}${server.graphqlPath}, weburl = ${webUrl}`
    )
  );
};

startServer();
```

Here is the React client

```
const serverUrl =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? "http://localhost:4000"
    : "https://server-domain.com";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: `${serverUrl}/graphql`,
  credentials: "include"
});

function App() {
  console.log(serverUrl, "uri");
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Routes/>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

- [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Yht.png) of the Network on localhost
- [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alQ7Z.png) of the cookie on localhost
- [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIiMB.png) of the Network in production
- [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wQoa.png) of the cookie (or lack thereof) in production
- [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmw1x.png) of the console in production
- [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm3kB.png) of the Heroku logging

As you can see, the sessions are being logged server side ... they just aren't making it to the client.

Banging my head against the wall -- would appreciate any help!

Any suggestions on how to fix this?